# Normalizing HTML content when requesting URL with Requests

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using Requests in Python 3.6 to get HTML content, with this code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/17/world/europe/trump-britain-obama-wiretap-gchq.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

However, the output has strange content with many "\n" characters:

```
 b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> <!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" itemid="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/17/world/europe/trump-britain-obama-wiretap-gchq.html" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle"  itemscope xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <!--<![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9 lt-ie10 section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt-ie10 lt-ie9 section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> 
 <![endif]-->\n<!--[if (lt IE 8)]> <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <![endif]
 -->\n<head>\n ..."
```

How can I fix it to get full standard HTML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.text` instead of `response.content` – as noted in the Requests documentation quoted below, this will decode the response content to a Unicode string, using the encoding information provided by the HTTP response:

> [**content**](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content)
>
> Content of the response, in bytes.

> [**text**](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text)
>
> Content of the response, in unicode.
>
> If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using chardet.
>
> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing this property.

Example:

```python
import requests
url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/17/world/europe/trump-britain-obama-wiretap-gchq.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> <!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" itemid="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/17/world/europe/trump-britain-obama-wiretap-gchq.html" itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle"  itemscope xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9 lt-ie10 section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt-ie10 lt-ie9 section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (lt IE 8)]> <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 section-europe format-medium tone-news app-article page-theme-standard has-comments has-top-ad type-size-small has-large-lede" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Trump Offers No Apology for Claim on British Spying - The New York Times</title>
      <!-- etc ... -->
</body>
</html>
```